# conflicting python2 and python3 in making app

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, python-2.x, buildozer

I am trying to make an app using kivy, python.
kivy works with python3.

on the other hand, when I want to run buildozer to make the app, in the "android-ndk-r20b" folder, I have the file "smtpd.py" which mentioned that:  "Please note that this script requires Python 2.0"

So, I got syntax error while python2 and python3 have some conflicts.

What should I do?

Comment: From which package is smtpd.py?  https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtpd.html -> `smtpd should be considered deprecated.` Using deprecated stuff doesn't work in all cases.

Comment: I don't know why this is happening for some people, this script is not important and should be ignored. You could try just deleting it or moving it out of the ndk folder, although this is a hacky workaround.